# How do I take a json key and turn it into a CSS style

Tags: jquery, html, json

I'm trying to fill a bar if a user votes so if the value "score" in my json file is 10 then jQuery must add 10% of color red to the to the bar:

JQuery Code:

```
   $(document).ready( function(){
        $.getJSON( "js/json/sidekicks.json", function(obj){
            $.each(obj.Sidekicks, function(key, value){
                $('div#sidekicks' + value.Id + 'span.red-line-fill').text(value.Score);
            });
        });
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="sidekicks" class="side-kick-holder">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                    <a href="" >
                        <div id="1098" class="hit super-box shuv-down-10" >

                            <h4>Rose Tyler <span class="thin">(Dr Who)</span>
                            <div class="circle"><img id="red-tick" class="change-img" data-alt-src="img/circle-hover.png" src="img/circle-grey.png" alt="circle"></div>
                            </h4>

                            <div class="line-grey"><span class="red_line_fill"></span></div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

this is my json file with all the values:

```
{
"Sidekicks": [
    {
        "Id": 1098,     // this will be the sidekick "Rose Tyler(Dr Who)" but this name can change at any time;
        "Score": 20     
    },
    {
        "Id": 1099,     // this will be the sidekick "Dr Watson" but this name can change at any time;
        "Score": 10
    },
    {
        "Id": 1100,     // this will be the sidekick "Chewbacca" but this name can change at any time;
        "Score": 30
    },
    {
        "Id": 1101,     // this will be the sidekick "Robin" but this name can change at any time;
        "Score": 10
    },
    {
        "Id": 1102,     // this will be the sidekick "Donkey (from Shrek)" but this name can change at any time;
        "Score": 20
    },
    {
        "Id": 1103,     // this will be the sidekick "Gromit" but this name can change at any time;
        "Score": 10
    }
]
```

}

Comment: `$('div#sidekicks').find('span.red-line-fill').text(value.Score).attr('width', value.Score+'%');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
var color = (score / 100) * 255;
$('#example-selector').css('background-color', 'rgb(color + ', 0, 0)');
```

This should work this way: High score (100, I presume), will be full RED, #FF0000.
And Lowest score (0, I presume), will be full BLACK.

Just implement this at your code.

---

Best answer:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    var MAX_WIDTH = 100; // Define max bar width in Pixels here
    $.getJSON( "js/json/sidekicks.json", function(obj){
        $.each(obj.Sidekicks, function(key, value){
            var color = 'rgb(' + ((value.Score / 100) * 255) + ', 0, 0';
            var width = (value.Score / 100) * MAX_WIDTH;
            $('div#' + value.Id).find('.red_line_fill').text(value.Score).css("background-color", color).width(width);
        });
    });
});
```

The behavior of this code is that for each bar, it will change the color proportionally to score (where 0 is black and 100 is pure red), and width (where 0 is 0 pixels and 100 is MAX_WIDTH value in pixels).

Please verify for any javascript erros, because is late night here and maybe I missed something out.

Comment: that code does not seem to be working ill keep trying would you like to see the json file if it will be of any help

Comment: I assumed that you want to change background color, but if you want to change text color, just change from 'background-color' to 'color'

Comment: I modified a little bit the code:
css value was wrong, now is correct.

Comment: ill explain it to you i have a json file with values like this -> "Id": 1098, "Score": 20 this values must be linked to my html and the line must fill so if the Score is 20 then the class red_line_fill the width must increase by 20% see

Comment: Hmm... So, your expected result is a bar with the width proportional to the score value, and color proportional in red to your score value too?

Comment: this last line of code must be affected <div class="line-grey"><span class="red_line_fill"></span></div> : so the span.red_line_fill must change based on the json file

Comment: i modified my code an added the json data check the main code above that should give you a better understanding

Comment: Ok, i will do a new answer soon.

Comment: the code is not working, wait keep in mind the bar will be red as soon as someone votes so theres only red no black and red must just fill up when the value of score in the json file changes

Comment: +50 shot man you are the king of kings it worked thank you sooooooo much